# Does anybody know of an Atom APP server for .Net?

Tags: .net, windows, atom-feed, atompub

I'm aware of the Argotic framework for .Net that assists in the collation and management of Atom data, but does anybody know of a .Net application/framework that implements the Atom Publishing Protocol (APP)?

Creating a .Net APP server from scratch seems a daunting task, even if it 'stands on the shoulders' of Argotic.  Maybe a .Net rewrite of Apache Abdera (or other O/S implementation) would be easier.

I welcome your thoughts,

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just published "Atom Publishing Protocol server library for ASP.NET" - see http://www.jhsoft.com/atompub-sl.aspx